# postgresql to return the highest 5 salaried employees

Tags: postgresql

assuming the table employee (eid int,ename text,dept text,salary integer)
I am supposed to write query  the highest 5 salaried employees,

I tired select max(salary) as highestsalary from employee
and was able to pull , but I don't know how to include the 5

Comment: What if there are ties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can order by salary (descending) and then limit to the first 5 rows. For example:

```
select *
from employee
order by salary desc
limit 5
```

Comment: This returns 5 of the highest paid employees, which is not necessarily the same thing.